# How to allow a user 'edit' on activities?

Tags: drupal, activities, acl

Users have ACL 'edit' access to a group, and can access the contacts in the group OK.  They can create an activity, but then cannot edit it - for each activity they just get 'View' and 'File on Case' possibilities and not 'Edit'.  There are no  permissions to edit activities - only view and delete.  How can I allow them to edit activities?  Using 5.6 and Drupal

Comment: Have you tried doing this using Webform CiviCRM?

Comment: You mention "File on Case" - if your users **can** edit activities that are ***not*** associated with cases, check to see if you have either the "CiviCase: access my cases and activities" (view and edit only those cases managed by this user) or the "CiviCase: access all cases and activities" (view and edit all cases for visible contacts) permissions enabled for the given role?

Comment: Tony - this is using the regular back office UI.  Although I guess a webform would also work, so will give it a try

Comment: Tamar - I checked the permission you suggested but it made no difference - they have these permission although the problem here is with regular activities, not case activities.  
I notice that this problem has come up before, with no solution, although some users don't have this problem at all so it must be something to with this groups of users access.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem by changing ACLs.  Originally the user was in role 'A' and the contact where they could create but not edit an activity was in group 'B' - and role 'A' had edit access to group 'B'. By changing the target contact to be in the same group as the 'A' role and giving that role 'edit' access to itself (its group) then they get edit access to activities.  As it happened, putting the target contact into this group is OK but this might not always be the case.  Seems like 'edit activities' should be a permission - this has been discussed before.